# event bubbling for combobox item selection which is inside the datagridview

Tags: c#, events, datagridview

i have a datagrid combobox column, binded some data from database to  comboboxcolumn
i have to raise an event for selection of combobox item please help me, i used the following code in program.cs

`this.datagrdADDTEMP.SelectionChanged+= new System.EventHandler(this.dgv_SelectionChanged);`

In form.cs

`void dgv_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){}`

but it raising the event when im clicking the cell, i want to raise the event when i select the item from the combobox. please help me im new to this concept event bubbling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're using the DataGridView's SelectionChanged event, not a ComboBox event.

Try handling the EditingControlShowing event (make sure to actually hook it up in the code or in the designer):

```
    string str = null;

    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        var cell = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (cell != null)
        {
            cell.SelectedIndexChanged -= doWork;
            cell.SelectedIndexChanged += doWork;
        }
    }

    private void doWork(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = dataGridView1.EditingControl as ComboBox;
        if (tb != null)
            str = tb.SelectedValue != null ? tb.SelectedValue.ToString() : null;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much it helped a lot...and please let me know the code for storing the selected value in the string please help me...thank you in advance